# Integrating $x^3 \sqrt{x^2+1} $

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need to solve this integral $\int x^3 \sqrt{x^2+1} dx$
Someone could explain to me how?

I have tried to use substitutions, i.e. $x^2+1$ and  $\sqrt{x^2+1}$; but seems like its not correct. Someone could explain to me how?

Comment: Both substitutions you say you tried work perfectly. Please show the work you did to "try" them.

Comment: ohh i didn't think of squaring the substitution. sorry, i'm very new to integration...

Comment: Letting $t=x^2$, your integral becomes $~\dfrac12\displaystyle\int t~\sqrt{t+1}~dt$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The substitution $u=\sqrt{x^2+1}$, or equivalently $u^2=x^2+1$, works nicely. We get $u\,du=x\,dx$. Borrow an $x$ from $x^3$ to keep $dx$ company.

We want 
$$\int x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}\,\, x\,dx.$$
The term $x^2$ is $u^2-1$. The term $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ is $u$. And finally the $x\,dx$ part is $u\,du$.

Answer (score 2):

By substituting $x=\sinh t$ we have:
$$ I = \int \sinh^3 t\cosh^2 t\,dt =\int \sinh^3 t\,dt + \int\sinh^5 t\,dt.$$
Just turn $\sinh t$ into $\frac{e^t-e^{-t}}{2}$ and integrate termwise what you get through the binomial theorem.